# first order: show that $\forall x (\phi \vee \psi) =\hspace{-.4em}|\models (\phi \vee \forall x \psi)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

first order: show that $\forall x (\phi \vee \psi) =\hspace{-.4em}|\models (\phi \vee  \forall x \psi)$ if $x \notin free(\phi)$, where $=\hspace{-.4em}|\models$ denotes logically equivalent.

I don't see why these are logically equivalent. It must hinge on x being bounded

Comment: In the title of the question you have "v" and "$\land$"; in the body you write "$\lor$" on both sides. Are you having trouble with the difference between "$\land$" and "$\lor$"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm sorry, no I goofed in my typing. I will edit

Comment: The key-point is : $x ∉ free(ϕ)$. You can prove it with *Natural Deduction*, showing : $∀x(ϕ∨ψ)⊢(ϕ∨∀xψ)$ and $(ϕ∨∀xψ)⊢∀x(ϕ∨ψ)$ and then using *soundness*. In both derivations, you need in an essential way the above proviso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of *ϕ* as a constant as far as the variable *x*, and the quantifier are concerned. The quantifier does no work in *ϕ*, so excluding *ϕ* from the quantifier's scope doesn't affect the truth of the the entire formula. So both formulae are logically equivalent.